# Overriding Sphinx autodoc "Alias of" for import of private class?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a Python package that I am attempting to document with sphinx-autodoc. My python package has an `__init__.py` file that imports a class out from a submodule to make it accessible at the package level.

```
from a.b.c.d import _Foo as Foo

__all__ = ["Foo"]
```

If I do this, my (html) documentation is as follows:

> **a.b.c package**
>
> **Submodules**
>
> **a.b.c.d module**
>
> *[snip documentation of irrelevant public classes within the a.b.c.d module]*
>
> **Module contents**
>
> The c module.
>
> a.b.c.**Foo**
>
> alias of **_Foo**

Not super useful since `_Foo` is (rightly) undocumented as it is a private class within the a.b.c.d submodule.

I can add the following to my `conf.py` which ensures that the *private* class definition in the module is documented.

```
def skip(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    if name == "_Foo":
        return False
    return skip
```

Other alternative, but not great things I've tried:

1. Rename `a.b.c.d._Foo` to `a.b.c.d.Foo` (and then update the import to `from a.b.c.d import Foo`) -- but then I get the class documented twice, once under the **a.b.c.d module** heading, and once again under the **Module contents** heading.
2. Renaming `a.b.c.d.Foo` to `a.b.c.d.MyFoo` and then importing (`from a.b.c.d import MyFoo as Foo`) results in `MyFoo` being documented, and `Foo` being listed as an alias of `MyFoo`.

---

Ideally I'd like the private definition to remain undocumented, but to have the version imported into the package fully documented. Does anyone know how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Sphinx uses the `__name__` and `__module__` members of the class, and the `__module__` member of the owner of the class to figure out if it is an alias or the real thing. You can trick Sphinx in thinking that your imported class is the real one by setting these members explicitly.

```py
from a.b.c.d import _Foo as Foo
Foo.__module__ = __name__
Foo.__name__ = 'Foo'
```

Comment: If you do this then you break `inspect.getsource(Foo)`

Comment: Do this in the `setup` function in `conf.py` and then you won't mess with anything in the original source code. For example: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/6af9e1008702fb0fab939bf2154bbf93dfe84a16/docs/conf.py#L380-L394

Answer (score 1):

Using the `members` directive you can show all members except those that start with '_'. You can leave `_Foo` undocumented in a.b.c.d and document it as `Foo` in a.b.c. I would import `_Foo` as `from a.b.c.d import _Foo` and then add whatever documentation like:

```
Foo = _Foo
''' blah blah blah '''
```

If, for some reason, you don't want _Foo in a.b.c's namespace, then you can also do:

```
from a.b.c.d import _Foo as Foo
Foo = Foo
''' blah blah blah '''
```