# generate documentation for class defined in a function

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Using the source below, i want to generate documentation for the class foo defined in the function.

```
# module named rubbish.py
def factory():
    class foo:
        def bar(self):
            '''bar
            '''
            pass
```

the corresponding rst file looks so

```
rubbish module
==============

.. automodule:: rubbish
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

and the class documentation does not get generated. The generated html shows only factory().

Is there any directive to document the class too?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27337534/407651, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12039633/407651

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this in a perhaps round about way, but it seems to work.

- I have not tested this "from scratch"
- I am using autodoc

#### Code

my_module.py:

```py
# here lies the class factory
def foo_factory():
  class Foo:
    '''My Foo class is cool'''

    def __init__(self):
      '''Init a Foo 
      Params
      ------
      etc..
      '''
      pass

    def bar(self):
      '''do a bar! 
      Params
      ------
      etc..
      '''
      return 1+1
  
  foo_factory.class_example = Foo # <--Note A.1
```

Add the following to your sphinx conf.py:

```py
def setup(app):
    import my_module
    example = my_module.foo_factory() # <-- Note A.2

    my_module.Foo = my_module.foo_factory.class_example # <--Note A.3
    my_module.Foo.__name__ = 'Foo'# <--Note B.1
    my_module.Foo.__module__ = 'my_module' # <--Note B.2
```

Add to your module rst file (where the documented class should appear):

```
.. autoclass:: Foo
   :members:
```

#### Explanation

**A.1** Make the class accessible outside of the local (foo_factory) scope

**A.2** It will only be accessible after invoking the factory, so we "dummy" invoke it here.

The inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12039980/4996681

**A.3**
Add the class as an attribute of your module

**B**
After doing the steps in **A**  (and adding the class to the rst file), sphinx did add the class to the documentation, but it appeared as "alias of `my_module.foo_factory.<locals>.Foo`".

To override the alias, we fool sphinx into thinking the class is a class directly in your module.

The inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58982001/4996681