# sphinx hyperlinking to members of a Python module that is imported under an alias

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I maintain a Python package that is usually imported with a short standardized nickname, in the manner of `import numpy as np` or `import pandas as pd`.   Let's say it's `import foobar as fb`.

I am using sphinx to document it, and in my `conf.py` I have `'sphinx.ext.autodoc'` among my `extensions`, and `default_role = 'py:obj'`.  This is a nice setup, because it means that whenever my docstrings or separate `.rst` files contain an uncluttered string like

```
See the `foobar.Thing` class documentation for more details.
```

or even just

```
See the `Thing` class documentation for more details.
```

then the text within backticks automatically gets hyperlinked to the documentation for the `foobar.Thing` class.   But what's missing is the ability to do this:

```
See the `fb.Thing` class documentation for more details.
```

The text `fb.Thing` does not get hyperlinked, because sphinx (or sphinx autodoc) does not know that `fb` is an alias for the `foobar` package.  How do I tell it that this is the case?

NB: I know it's possible to do it with `<>` notation:

```
See the `fb.Thing <foobar.Thing>` class documentation for more details.
```

but the docstrings are designed to be read as plain text as well, so I'm hoping that this can be done without introducing this or other forms of `` :clutter:`...` `` into them, but rather somehow in the `conf.py` file or in the `.. automodule::` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This might be solvable with intersphinx. If a name isn't found in the local object inventory, it can search in external sources. You can add you own documentation as a intersphinx inventory.

**Intersphinx configuration:**

```
# ==============================================================================
# Sphinx.Ext.InterSphinx
# ==============================================================================
intersphinx_mapping = {
#  'python':       ('https://docs.python.org/3', None),
  'foobar': ('http://foobar.readthedocs.io/en/latest', None),
}
```

**Usage:**

```
At next, I want to document `fb.Thing <foobar:Thing>`, because it's a great implementation.
```

**Further Resources:**

- Intersphinx documentation: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html
- Sometimes, Sphinx can handle aliases: [Overriding Sphinx autodoc "Alias of" for import of private class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765577/overriding-sphinx-autodoc-alias-of-for-import-of-private-class)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  With the same number of additional characters, it's actually possible to do the same thing without intersphinx:   `\`fb.Thing <foobar.Thing>\`` (note the dot instead of the colon).  But ideally I was trying to avoid this additional clutter in the docstring itself.

Comment: Does Python know that `fb` is an alias to `foobar`? So I mean, is there any special attribute like `__module__` or similar, that would give a Python introspection code the possibility to see/find aliases? If not, I think it would be impossible to even extend Sphinx in a native way to create internal alias tables...

Comment: It would be fairly easy to "tell Python" this fact in various ways. You could, for example, duplicate the entry in `sys.modules` by saying `sys.modules['fb'] = sys.modules['foobar']`.   And this duplication will be identifiable by any code that cares to inspect the `__name__` attribute of the modules found there, since  `fb.__name__` is going to be equal to `'foobar'`.

Comment: But I assume, you don't want to rewrite all import statements to that style, right?

Comment: No, but it could be done in `conf.py`. It only needs to be the case while Sphinx is running, I presume?

Comment: @jez I think this would create doubled items in the module index and other doubled items and objects all over in the documentation ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make sphinx aware of the module aliases, but this might be close to your desired notation:

`somefile.py`:

```py
"""
Some documentation with references to an externally documented function

:func:`numpy.searchsorted` or :func:`partial.update_wrapper`
"""
```

`conf.py`:

```py
# intersphinx settings
intersphinx_mapping = {'numpy': ('https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy', None),
                       'functools': ('https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html', None)}
```